# Why do I need to specify rows unbounded in this query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm doing SQL exercises at [WindowFunctions.com](https://www.windowfunctions.com/questions/over/3). The task is to cumulatively sum cats' weights from heaviest to lightest. The table looks like:

| name | weight | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ashes | 4.5 | ... |
| Tigger | 3.8 | ... |
| Smokey | 6.1 | ... |
| ... |  |  |

My first guess was

```
SELECT 
name,
SUM(weight) OVER (ORDER BY weight DESC) AS running_total_weight
FROM cats
```

However, it produces wrong result which sums first two cats into first cumulative sum.

| name | running_total_weight |
| --- | --- |
| Smokey | 12.2 |
| Oscar | 12.2 |
| ... |  |
| Tigger | 61.1 |

If I, however, run the same query ascending, the summation is done correctly, and Tiger has weight 3.8 and not 8.0.

The site suggests solution: rewrite `OVER ()` clause as `OVER (ORDER BY weight DESC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. Why does it works? Why is it needed when summation descending and not needed when descending?

Comment: "By default, if ORDER BY is supplied then the frame consists of all rows from the start of the partition up through the current row, **plus any following rows that are equal to the current row according to the ORDER BY clause**"  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html

Comment: @jjanes, yes, but that does not explain the difference between the two queries :-)

Comment: I get 61.1 for both `Smokey` and `Oscar` when running `SUM(weight) OVER (ORDER BY weight asc)` so that suggests the logic works the same when two cats weight the same and that the extra `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is necessary. Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your question though? Or rather... it's not `tigger` that is the problem, it's `Smokey` and `Oscar` sharing the same weight that you are being asked to figure out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is not the `unbounded preceding`.
The point is the default framing behavior when `over (order by...)` is used, which is `range` (and not `rows`).

```
select *
 
      --rows
      ,sum(c) over(order by c rows unbounded preceding)                          rows1
      ,sum(c) over(order by c rows between unbounded preceding and current row)  rows2

      --range
      ,sum(c) over(order by c)                                                   range1
      ,sum(c) over(order by c range unbounded preceding)                         range2
      ,sum(c) over(order by c range between unbounded preceding and current row) range3

from (values (10),(20),(20),(20),(30)) t(c)
```

| c | rows1 | rows2 | range1 | range2 | range3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 20 | 30 | 30 | 70 | 70 | 70 |
| 20 | 50 | 50 | 70 | 70 | 70 |
| 20 | 70 | 70 | 70 | 70 | 70 |
| 30 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 | 100 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0ce95100938d23e2e890bf683cf8c3a0)